# MediaWiki Templates & Layout

Tags: mediawiki

I have set up an internal MediaWiki site to build a knowledge base for our internal team.  Currently I want to set up one category of articles and expand on that if it is well received.

I am brand new to MediaWiki & wiki's in general and I am struggling through the documentation to achieve what I want.

What I would like is navigation on the side panel for high level categories, which would then take to a page that lists out all the articles in that category.  Each document created in the category would have a template with headings to fill in (i.e. "Executive Summary, Problem Summary, Details, etc").  When a user creates a new document in Topic1 they would be presented with a prefilled page and expected to fill in information under those headings.

Is this possible to set up or am I using the wrong tool to do so?

Comment: I think I have the category layout down, but I am still unclear as to how to enforce a page creation use a template (or create one).

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like is navigation on the side panel for high level
>   categories

For this you would edit `MediaWiki:Sidebar` (in all built in skins. If using a custom skin, things may look different).

> Each document created in the category would have a template with headings to fill in (i.e. "Executive 
>   Summary, Problem Summary, Details, etc"). When a user creates a new document in Topic1 they would be 
>   presented with a prefilled page and expected to fill in information under those headings.

There are a few different extensions that provide that kind of functionality, like e.g. [Extension:NewArticleTemplate](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aNewArticleTemplate) and [Extension:NewArticleTemplate](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aNewArticleTemplate). With those you can give users that create a new article a default template to work with:

```
{{My Template
| Executive Summary =   write yout sumamry here
| Problem Summary   =   ...
}}
```

For more advanced things, you can try out Semantic MediaWiki with Semantic Forms